# Incorrectly aligned table from visual Fox

Tags: visual-foxpro

I wrote a program in visual foxpro in which I am trying to align some data in a table. For now it looks like this:

```
============================================================================                        
No.     Last Name                |  Number book              |    Price              |
=====================================================================================                             
|    1 | JOHN SMITH               | ISBN12345678945643489       |      26       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2 | SAMUEL LEE JACKSON          | ISBN1466487264826384       |     208       |
```

I am trying to correctly align all columns. But if the name is longer or shorter, then the second cell also shifts.

The line of code that I am using is:

```
? '|',STR(N,4),'|',(ALLTRIM(NAME)),'|      ',ALLTRIM(BOOKNO),'|',+STR(PRICE,7),'      |'
```

I gave the name a maximum of 30 characters.

Comment: Although I mostly agree with Stefan's answer (and upvoted), any particular reason to dump out to scree instead of doing a report?  Or is this just for learning and getting started in the VFP world.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PadL() / PadR() to get equally sized strings from your single string or numeric expressions.

And for the column alignment, since your code looks as if want an output on something like the VFP `_screen` or on a `Form`, you'd need to use a mono-spaced font on that object.

Command Window example:

```
lcPreviousFont = _screen.FontName
_screen.FontName = "Courier"
SCAN
    ? TEXTMERGE("|<<PADR(n, 4)>>|<<PADR(name, 20)>>|<<PADR(bookno, 30)>>|<<PADL(price, 7)>>|")
ENDSCAN
_screen.FontName = m.lcPreviousFont
```